# Update Cocoa interface from c++

Tags: c++, cocoa, opengl, objective-c++

I'm working on a mac project using cocoa. Currently I have a NSOpenGLView with a game loop written in C++. That game loop is responsible for a lot of the application's logic and it should trigger changes in the rest of the cocoa interface. For example, it should populate a NSCollectionView.

Calling C++ from Objective-C++ is easy, but how would I go about making changes in the cocoa interface from the game loop? I would also like to keep some sort of decoupling between UI and the game loop so that I can easily port the application to other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project using C++11?

You can write a set of handlers using C++ lambdas (i.e. blocks), which will be fired upon some events in game loop (portable at this moment). And then some concrete implementation for specific platform can execute it's code from this block. Things like populating NSCollectionViews can easily grab data from C++ side when fired from such block and update UI accordingly.